# hardcoded sting "x", should use @string resource

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I got this error in my xml file in the layout folder. I changed it to android:text="@string/x" but then it shows this on the buttons: [image]

Here is my main_menu.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Menu" //warning here
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/one_player"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="1player" />//warning here

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/two_player"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="2players" />//warning here

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit_game"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_height="115dp"
        android:text="exitgame" />//warning here

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define strings under res->values->string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string
        name="player_1"
        1player</string>
</resources>
```

In this way you can refer the string value in you xml layout file under any view by:-

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/one_player"
    android:layout_width="115dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/player_1" />
```

You can refer the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) for more details about how to declair strings in resources.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot to actually declare the variables in `strings.xml`.

Comment: I did forget to declare them in strings.xml indeed, very dumb of me

Comment: This post should be a comment. Not an answer.